# Android api 24 background altbeacon monitoring does not work

Tags: android, altbeacon, android-7.0-nougat, beacon

**Hi, I've an app working stable on android 6.0 and 5.0, it detects beacons in region even if the app is killed. But when i install the application on Sony Z5 that has android N version, it only detects on foreground. Below is the logs when application is killed. Scan started but no detection occurs. Is there a known bug on api 24?**

```
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication, BootstrapNotifier {

private static final String BEACON_TAG = "BeaconModule";

// TODO get server url from gradle
public static final String SERVER_URL = "";

private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
        return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
        return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
                new MainReactPackage(),
                new VectorIconsPackage(),
                new RNSharedPreferencesReactPackage()
        );
    }
};

@Override
public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);

    initializeBeaconManager();

}

private void initializeBeaconManager() {
    new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);
    BeaconManager beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().clear();
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
    beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(10000L);
    beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(30000L);
    initializeBeaconRegions();
}

public void initializeBeaconRegions() {
    BeaconManager beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    List<Region> regions = new ArrayList<Region>();

    /* here is some stuff to get new regions from server*/

    List<Region> deleteRegions = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Region mRegion : beaconManager.getMonitoredRegions()) {
        if (!regions.contains(mRegion)) {
            deleteRegions.add(mRegion);
        }
    }
    for (Region delRegion : deleteRegions) {
        beaconManager.getMonitoredRegions().remove(delRegion);
    }

    new RegionBootstrap(this, regions);
}

@Override
public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
    Log.d(BEACON_TAG, "did enter region.");
}

@Override
public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
    Log.d(BEACON_TAG, "did exit region.");
}

@Override
public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int i, Region region) {
}}
```

04-13 17:51:31.343 3524-3543/com.workzonemobile D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
04-13 17:51:31.345 11401-11433/? D/BtGatt.GattService: stopScan() - queue size =1
04-13 17:51:31.347 11401-11424/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: stop scan
04-13 17:51:31.352 11401-11456/? D/BtGatt.GattService: unregisterClient() - clientIf=5
04-13 17:51:31.360 3524-3543/com.workzonemobile D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
04-13 17:51:31.362 11401-11421/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onScanFilterParamsConfigured() - clientIf=5, status=0, action=1, availableSpace=16
04-13 17:51:31.362 11401-11421/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: callback done for clientIf - 5 status - 0
04-13 17:51:31.362 11401-11424/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams() - queue=0
04-13 17:51:31.362 11401-11424/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams() - ScanSetting Scan mode=-2147483648 mLastConfiguredScanSetting=0
04-13 17:51:31.362 11401-11424/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams() - queue emtpy, scan stopped
04-13 17:51:31.367 11401-11456/? D/BtGatt.GattService: registerClient() - UUID=25b0c522-5506-4976-8843-d57fa774c50b
04-13 17:51:31.368 11401-11421/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onClientRegistered() - UUID=25b0c522-5506-4976-8843-d57fa774c50b, clientIf=5
04-13 17:51:31.368 3524-3538/com.workzonemobile D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5 mClientIf=0
04-13 17:51:31.369 11401-11455/? D/BtGatt.GattService: start scan with filters
04-13 17:51:31.374 11401-11424/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: handling starting scan
04-13 17:51:31.379 11401-11421/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onScanFilterEnableDisabled() - clientIf=5, status=0, action=1
04-13 17:51:31.379 11401-11421/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: callback done for clientIf - 5 status - 0
04-13 17:51:31.379 11401-11424/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureFilterParamter 500 10000 1 0
04-13 17:51:31.381 11401-11421/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onScanFilterParamsConfigured() - clientIf=5, status=0, action=0, availableSpace=15
04-13 17:51:31.381 11401-11421/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: callback done for clientIf - 5 status - 0
04-13 17:51:31.381 11401-11424/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams() - queue=1
04-13 17:51:31.381 11401-11424/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams() - ScanSetting Scan mode=2 mLastConfiguredScanSetting=-2147483648
04-13 17:51:31.381 11401-11424/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams - scanInterval = 8000configureRegularScanParams - scanWindow = 8000
04-13 17:51:31.383 11401-11421/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onScanParamSetupCompleted : 0
04-13 17:51:32.310 2102-1620/? I/BroadcastQueue: am_broadcast_enqueue: [background,0,Intent { act=android.bluetooth.device.action.NAME_CHANGED flg=0x4000010 (has extras) },1]
04-13 17:51:32.312 2102-2135/? I/BroadcastQueue: am_broadcast_finished: [background,0,Intent { act=android.bluetooth.device.action.NAME_CHANGED flg=0x4000010 (has extras) }]
04-13 17:51:32.315 2102-5969/? I/BroadcastQueue: am_broadcast_enqueue: [background,0,Intent { act=android.bluetooth.device.action.CLASS_CHANGED flg=0x4000010 (has extras) },2]
04-13 17:51:32.317 2102-2135/? I/BroadcastQueue: am_broadcast_finished: [background,0,Intent { act=android.bluetooth.device.action.CLASS_CHANGED flg=0x4000010 (has extras) }]
04-13 17:51:32.500 9120-9120/? I/libmdmdetect: ESOC framework not supported
04-13 17:51:32.500 9120-9120/? I/libmdmdetect: Found internal modem: modem
04-13 17:51:32.497 9120-9120/? W/qcom-system-dae: type=1400 audit(0.0:266131): avc: denied { read write } for name="diag" dev="tmpfs" ino=1993 scontext=u:r:qcomsysd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:diag_device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=0 ppid=1 pcomm="init" pgid=1 pgcomm="init"
04-13 17:51:32.501 9120-9120/? E/QCOMSysDaemon: Can't find/open bootselect node: (No such file or directory)
04-13 17:51:32.501 9120-9120/? I/QCOMSysDaemon: Starting qcom system daemon
04-13 17:51:32.501 9120-9120/? E/Diag_Lib:  Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 13
04-13 17:51:32.501 9120-9120/? E/QCOMSysDaemon:  Diag_LSM_Init failed : 0
04-13 17:51:35.278 11401-11401/? D/HeadsetPhoneState: Enter onSignalStrengthsChanged
04-13 17:51:35.279 11401-11401/? D/HeadsetPhoneState: Exit onSignalStrengthsChanged
04-13 17:51:36.945 2102-2135/? I/ActivityManager: Waited long enough for: ServiceRecord{f229130 u0 com.sonyericsson.advancedwidget.weather/com.sonymobile.weatherservice.service.WeatherService}
04-13 17:51:37.515 11020-11070/? V/ClClient: SEND(411)  KeepAliveRequest_4{}    UID:a8ad154c-6d6c-46fc-8ff1-6a86ef230e78
04-13 17:51:37.580 9193-9193/? I/libmdmdetect: ESOC framework not supported
04-13 17:51:37.577 9193-9193/? W/qcom-system-dae: type=1400 audit(0.0:266132): avc: denied { read write } for name="diag" dev="tmpfs" ino=1993 scontext=u:r:qcomsysd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:diag_device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=0 ppid=1 pcomm="init" pgid=1 pgcomm="init"
04-13 17:51:37.581 9193-9193/? I/libmdmdetect: Found internal modem: modem
04-13 17:51:37.582 9193-9193/? E/QCOMSysDaemon: Can't find/open bootselect node: (No such file or directory)
04-13 17:51:37.582 9193-9193/? I/QCOMSysDaemon: Starting qcom system daemon
04-13 17:51:37.582 9193-9193/? E/Diag_Lib:  Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 13
04-13 17:51:37.582 9193-9193/? E/QCOMSysDaemon:  Diag_LSM_Init failed : 0
04-13 17:51:37.782 11020-11068/? V/ClClient: RECV(411)  +0,3s   KeepAliveResponse_5{hasEstablishedSession=true}
04-13 17:51:41.332 2102-2388/? I/BroadcastQueue: am_broadcast_enqueue: [background,1,Intent { act=X.2U7.ACTION_ALARM.com.facebook.katana.Mqtt_Wakeup flg=0x14 pkg=com.facebook.katana (has extras) },1]
04-13 17:51:41.344 2102-2117/? I/BroadcastQueue: am_broadcast_finished: [background,1,Intent { act=X.2U7.ACTION_ALARM.com.facebook.katana.Mqtt_Wakeup flg=0x14 pkg=com.facebook.katana (has extras) }]
04-13 17:51:41.349 11401-11401/? D/HeadsetPhoneState: Enter onSignalStrengthsChanged
04-13 17:51:41.349 11401-11401/? D/HeadsetPhoneState: sendDeviceStateChanged. mService=1 mSignal=3 mRoam=0 mBatteryCharge=2
04-13 17:51:41.349 11401-11401/? D/HeadsetPhoneState: Exit onSignalStrengthsChanged
04-13 17:51:41.349 11401-11434/? D/HeadsetStateMachine: Disconnected process message: 11, size: 0
04-13 17:51:41.414 3524-3543/com.workzonemobile D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
04-13 17:51:41.415 11401-11412/? D/BtGatt.GattService: stopScan() - queue size =1
04-13 17:51:41.416 11401-11424/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: stop scan
04-13 17:51:41.416 11401-11413/? D/BtGatt.GattService: unregisterClient() - clientIf=5
04-13 17:51:41.422 3524-3543/com.workzonemobile D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
04-13 17:51:41.428 11401-11421/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onScanFilterParamsConfigured() - clientIf=5, status=0, action=1, availableSpace=16
04-13 17:51:41.428 11401-11421/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: callback done for clientIf - 5 status - 0
04-13 17:51:41.429 11401-11424/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams() - queue=0
04-13 17:51:41.429 11401-11424/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams() - ScanSetting Scan mode=-2147483648 mLastConfiguredScanSetting=2
04-13 17:51:41.429 11401-11424/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams() - queue emtpy, scan stopped
04-13 17:51:41.431 11401-11413/? D/BtGatt.GattService: registerClient() - UUID=35f07f8d-a3a2-4d71-9d28-1db8ad2262fc
04-13 17:51:41.433 11401-11421/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onClientRegistered() - UUID=35f07f8d-a3a2-4d71-9d28-1db8ad2262fc, clientIf=5
04-13 17:51:41.433 3524-3537/com.workzonemobile D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5 mClientIf=0
04-13 17:51:41.434 11401-11433/? D/BtGatt.GattService: start scan with filters
04-13 17:51:41.440 11401-11424/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: handling starting scan
04-13 17:51:41.445 11401-11421/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onScanFilterEnableDisabled() - clientIf=5, status=0, action=1
04-13 17:51:41.445 11401-11421/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: callback done for clientIf - 5 status - 0
04-13 17:51:41.445 11401-11424/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: addFilterToController: 5
04-13 17:51:41.447 11401-11421/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onScanFilterConfig() - clientIf=5, action = 0 status = 0, filterType=5, availableSpace=47
04-13 17:51:41.447 11401-11421/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: callback done for clientIf - 5 status - 0
04-13 17:51:41.447 11401-11424/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureFilterParamter 500 10000 1 0
04-13 17:51:41.449 11401-11421/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onScanFilterParamsConfigured() - clientIf=5, status=0, action=0, availableSpace=15
04-13 17:51:41.449 11401-11421/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: callback done for clientIf - 5 status - 0
04-13 17:51:41.449 11401-11424/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams() - queue=1
04-13 17:51:41.449 11401-11424/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams() - ScanSetting Scan mode=0 mLastConfiguredScanSetting=-2147483648
04-13 17:51:41.449 11401-11424/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams - scanInterval = 8000configureRegularScanParams - scanWindow = 800
04-13 17:51:41.456 11401-11421/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onScanParamSetupCompleted : 0
04-13 17:51:42.657 9273-9273/? W/qcom-system-dae: type=1400 audit(0.0:266133): avc: denied { read write } for name="diag" dev="tmpfs" ino=1993 scontext=u:r:qcomsysd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:diag_device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=0 ppid=1 pcomm="init" pgid=1 pgcomm="init"
04-13 17:51:42.663 9273-9273/? I/libmdmdetect: ESOC framework not supported
04-13 17:51:42.664 9273-9273/? I/libmdmdetect: Found internal modem: modem
04-13 17:51:42.664 9273-9273/? E/QCOMSysDaemon: Can't find/open bootselect node: (No such file or directory)
04-13 17:51:42.664 9273-9273/? I/QCOMSysDaemon: Starting qcom system daemon
04-13 17:51:42.664 9273-9273/? E/Diag_Lib:  Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 13
04-13 17:51:42.664 9273-9273/? E/QCOMSysDaemon:  Diag_LSM_Init failed : 0
04-13 17:51:44.236 11401-11401/? D/HeadsetPhoneState: Enter onSignalStrengthsChanged
04-13 17:51:44.237 11401-11401/? D/HeadsetPhoneState: Exit onSignalStrengthsChanged
04-13 17:51:46.477 11401-11401/? D/HeadsetPhoneState: Enter onSignalStrengthsChanged
04-13 17:51:46.478 11401-11401/? D/HeadsetPhoneState: sendDeviceStateChanged. mService=1 mSignal=0 mRoam=0 mBatteryCharge=2
04-13 17:51:46.478 11401-11401/? D/HeadsetPhoneState: Exit onSignalStrengthsChanged
04-13 17:51:46.478 11401-11434/? D/HeadsetStateMachine: Disconnected process message: 11, size: 0
04-13 17:51:47.550 11020-11070/? V/ClClient: SEND(412)  KeepAliveRequest_4{}    UID:95cae389-7bb7-456c-a60b-b460ab6802f6
04-13 17:51:47.728 9353-9353/? I/libmdmdetect: ESOC framework not supported
04-13 17:51:47.729 9353-9353/? I/libmdmdetect: Found internal modem: modem
04-13 17:51:47.717 9353-9353/? W/qcom-system-dae: type=1400 audit(0.0:266134): avc: denied { read write } for name="diag" dev="tmpfs" ino=1993 scontext=u:r:qcomsysd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:diag_device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=0 ppid=1 pcomm="init" pgid=1 pgcomm="init"
04-13 17:51:47.729 9353-9353/? E/QCOMSysDaemon: Can't find/open bootselect node: (No such file or directory)
04-13 17:51:47.729 9353-9353/? I/QCOMSysDaemon: Starting qcom system daemon
04-13 17:51:47.729 9353-9353/? E/Diag_Lib:  Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 13
04-13 17:51:47.729 9353-9353/? E/QCOMSysDaemon:  Diag_LSM_Init failed : 0
04-13 17:51:47.809 11020-11068/? V/ClClient: RECV(412)  +0,3s   KeepAliveResponse_5{hasEstablishedSession=true}
04-13 17:51:50.422 2102-2932/? I/BroadcastQueue: am_broadcast_enqueue: [background,0,Intent { act=android.bluetooth.device.action.NAME_CHANGED flg=0x4000010 (has extras) },1]
04-13 17:51:50.424 2102-2135/? I/BroadcastQueue: am_broadcast_finished: [background,0,Intent { act=android.bluetooth.device.action.NAME_CHANGED flg=0x4000010 (has extras) }]
04-13 17:51:50.427 2102-1617/? I/BroadcastQueue: am_broadcast_enqueue: [background,0,Intent { act=android.bluetooth.device.action.CLASS_CHANGED flg=0x4000010 (has extras) },2]
04-13 17:51:50.428 2102-2135/? I/BroadcastQueue: am_broadcast_finished: [background,0,Intent { act=android.bluetooth.device.action.CLASS_CHANGED flg=0x4000010 (has extras) }]
04-13 17:51:50.956 11401-11401/? D/HeadsetPhoneState: Enter onSignalStrengthsChanged
04-13 17:51:50.957 11401-11401/? D/HeadsetPhoneState: sendDeviceStateChanged. mService=1 mSignal=2 mRoam=0 mBatteryCharge=2
04-13 17:51:50.957 11401-11401/? D/HeadsetPhoneState: Exit onSignalStrengthsChanged
04-13 17:51:50.957 11401-11434/? D/HeadsetStateMachine: Disconnected process message: 11, size: 0
04-13 17:51:52.011 2102-1616/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 3592:com.foursquare.robin/u0a146 (adj 906): empty #17
04-13 17:51:52.062 2102-5710/? D/ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 3592
04-13 17:51:52.807 9421-9421/? W/qcom-system-dae: type=1400 audit(0.0:266135): avc: denied { read write } for name="diag" dev="tmpfs" ino=1993 scontext=u:r:qcomsysd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:diag_device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=0 ppid=1 pcomm="init" pgid=1 pgcomm="init"
04-13 17:51:52.813 9421-9421/? I/libmdmdetect: ESOC framework not supported
04-13 17:51:52.813 9421-9421/? I/libmdmdetect: Found internal modem: modem
04-13 17:51:52.813 9421-9421/? E/QCOMSysDaemon: Can't find/open bootselect node: (No such file or directory)
04-13 17:51:52.813 9421-9421/? I/QCOMSysDaemon: Starting qcom system daemon
04-13 17:51:52.814 9421-9421/? E/Diag_Lib:  Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 13
04-13 17:51:52.814 9421-9421/? E/QCOMSysDaemon:  Diag_LSM_Init failed : 0
04-13 17:51:53.198 11401-11401/? D/HeadsetPhoneState: Enter onSignalStrengthsChanged
04-13 17:51:53.199 11401-11401/? D/HeadsetPhoneState: sendDeviceStateChanged. mService=1 mSignal=0 mRoam=0 mBatteryCharge=2
04-13 17:51:53.199 11401-11401/? D/HeadsetPhoneState: Exit onSignalStrengthsChanged
04-13 17:51:53.200 11401-11434/? D/HeadsetStateMachine: Disconnected process message: 11, size: 0
04-13 17:51:57.551 11020-11070/? V/ClClient: SEND(413)  KeepAliveRequest_4{}    UID:03758b58-901d-47fc-8474-e020b3e27a6b
04-13 17:51:57.776 2102-2102/? I/BroadcastQueue: am_broadcast_enqueue: [background,0,Intent { act=android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED flg=0x60000010 (has extras) },27]
04-13 17:51:57.781 2534-2534/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: received broadcast android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
04-13 17:51:57.781 3186-3315/? W/QCNEJ: |CORE| CNE received unexpected action: android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
04-13 17:51:57.787 2495-2495/? D/TransmitPowerReceiver: Old PowerLevel: 6, current PowerLevel: 6
04-13 17:51:57.790 11401-11434/? D/HeadsetStateMachine: Disconnected process message: 10, size: 0
04-13 17:51:57.790 11401-11434/? D/HeadsetStateMachine: Enter processIntentBatteryChanged()
04-13 17:51:57.790 11401-11434/? D/HeadsetStateMachine: Exit processIntentBatteryChanged()
04-13 17:51:57.790 11401-11434/? D/HeadsetStateMachine: Exit Disconnected processMessage() 
04-13 17:51:57.792 2102-2135/? I/BroadcastQueue: am_broadcast_finished: [background,0,Intent { act=android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED flg=0x60000010 (has extras) }]
04-13 17:51:57.795 2534-2534/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: handleBatteryUpdate
04-13 17:51:57.857 9496-9496/? W/qcom-system-dae: type=1400 audit(0.0:266136): avc: denied { read write } for name="diag" dev="tmpfs" ino=1993 scontext=u:r:qcomsysd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:diag_device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=0 ppid=1 pcomm="init" pgid=1 pgcomm="init"
04-13 17:51:57.867 9496-9496/? I/libmdmdetect: ESOC framework not supported
04-13 17:51:57.868 9496-9496/? I/libmdmdetect: Found internal modem: modem
04-13 17:51:57.868 9496-9496/? E/QCOMSysDaemon: Can't find/open bootselect node: (No such file or directory)
04-13 17:51:57.868 9496-9496/? I/QCOMSysDaemon: Starting qcom system daemon
04-13 17:51:57.868 9496-9496/? E/Diag_Lib:  Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 13
04-13 17:51:57.868 9496-9496/? E/QCOMSysDaemon:  Diag_LSM_Init failed : 0
04-13 17:51:57.910 11020-11068/? V/ClClient: RECV(413)  +0,4s   KeepAliveResponse_5{hasEstablishedSession=true}
04-13 17:51:59.588 11401-11401/? D/HeadsetPhoneState: Enter onSignalStrengthsChanged
04-13 17:51:59.588 11401-11401/? D/HeadsetPhoneState: sendDeviceStateChanged. mService=1 mSignal=2 mRoam=0 mBatteryCharge=2
04-13 17:51:59.588 11401-11401/? D/HeadsetPhoneState: Exit onSignalStrengthsChanged
04-13 17:51:59.589 11401-11434/? D/HeadsetStateMachine: Disconnected process message: 11, size: 0
04-13 17:52:02.154 11401-11401/? D/HeadsetPhoneState: Enter onSignalStrengthsChanged
04-13 17:52:02.155 11401-11401/? D/HeadsetPhoneState: Exit onSignalStrengthsChanged
04-13 17:52:02.947 9577-9577/? W/qcom-system-dae: type=1400 audit(0.0:266137): avc: denied { read write } for name="diag" dev="tmpfs" ino=1993 scontext=u:r:qcomsysd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:diag_device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=0 ppid=1 pcomm="init" pgid=1 pgcomm="init"
04-13 17:52:02.952 9577-9577/? I/libmdmdetect: ESOC framework not supported
04-13 17:52:02.952 9577-9577/? I/libmdmdetect: Found internal modem: modem
04-13 17:52:02.952 9577-9577/? E/QCOMSysDaemon: Can't find/open bootselect node: (No such file or directory)
04-13 17:52:02.952 9577-9577/? I/QCOMSysDaemon: Starting qcom system daemon
04-13 17:52:02.953 9577-9577/? E/Diag_Lib:  Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 13
04-13 17:52:02.953 9577-9577/? E/QCOMSysDaemon:  Diag_LSM_Init failed : 0
04-13 17:52:04.396 11401-11401/? D/HeadsetPhoneState: Enter onSignalStrengthsChanged
04-13 17:52:04.396 11401-11401/? D/HeadsetPhoneState: Exit onSignalStrengthsChanged
04-13 17:52:07.551 11020-11070/? V/ClClient: SEND(414)  KeepAliveRequest_4{}    UID:e30cefc4-a17c-4fae-95d4-42b2f0d71d33
04-13 17:52:07.839 11020-11068/? V/ClClient: RECV(414)  +0,3s   KeepAliveResponse_5{hasEstablishedSession=true}
04-13 17:52:08.030 9646-9646/? I/libmdmdetect: ESOC framework not supported
04-13 17:52:08.031 9646-9646/? I/libmdmdetect: Found internal modem: modem
04-13 17:52:08.031 9646-9646/? E/QCOMSysDaemon: Can't find/open bootselect node: (No such file or directory)
04-13 17:52:08.031 9646-9646/? I/QCOMSysDaemon: Starting qcom system daemon
04-13 17:52:08.031 9646-9646/? E/Diag_Lib:  Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 13
04-13 17:52:08.031 9646-9646/? E/QCOMSysDaemon:  Diag_LSM_Init failed : 0
04-13 17:52:08.027 9646-9646/? W/qcom-system-dae: type=1400 audit(0.0:266138): avc: denied { read write } for name="diag" dev="tmpfs" ino=1993 scontext=u:r:qcomsysd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:diag_device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=0 ppid=1 pcomm="init" pgid=1 pgcomm="init"
04-13 17:52:08.879 11401-11401/? D/HeadsetPhoneState: Enter onSignalStrengthsChanged
04-13 17:52:08.879 11401-11401/? D/HeadsetPhoneState: sendDeviceStateChanged. mService=1 mSignal=3 mRoam=0 mBatteryCharge=2
04-13 17:52:08.879 11401-11401/? D/HeadsetPhoneState: Exit onSignalStrengthsChanged
04-13 17:52:08.880 11401-11434/? D/HeadsetStateMachine: Disconnected process message: 11, size: 0
04-13 17:52:11.116 11401-11401/? D/HeadsetPhoneState: Enter onSignalStrengthsChanged
04-13 17:52:11.117 11401-11401/? D/HeadsetPhoneState: Exit onSignalStrengthsChanged
04-13 17:52:11.332 3524-3543/com.workzonemobile D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
04-13 17:52:11.333 11401-11433/? D/BtGatt.GattService: stopScan() - queue size =1
04-13 17:52:11.335 11401-11424/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: stop scan
04-13 17:52:11.338 11401-11456/? D/BtGatt.GattService: unregisterClient() - clientIf=5
04-13 17:52:11.349 3524-3543/com.workzonemobile D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
04-13 17:52:11.351 11401-11421/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onScanFilterParamsConfigured() - clientIf=5, status=0, action=1, availableSpace=16
04-13 17:52:11.351 11401-11421/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: callback done for clientIf - 5 status - 0
04-13 17:52:11.351 11401-11424/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams() - queue=0
04-13 17:52:11.351 11401-11424/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams() - ScanSetting Scan mode=-2147483648 mLastConfiguredScanSetting=0
04-13 17:52:11.351 11401-11424/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams() - queue emtpy, scan stopped
04-13 17:52:11.355 11401-11413/? D/BtGatt.GattService: registerClient() - UUID=97dd9d99-06c9-41c0-8696-517aa5360489
04-13 17:52:11.356 11401-11421/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onClientRegistered() - UUID=97dd9d99-06c9-41c0-8696-517aa5360489, clientIf=5
04-13 17:52:11.356 3524-5572/com.workzonemobile D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5 mClientIf=0
04-13 17:52:11.357 11401-11456/? D/BtGatt.GattService: start scan with filters
04-13 17:52:11.364 11401-11424/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: handling starting scan
04-13 17:52:11.367 11401-11421/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onScanFilterEnableDisabled() - clientIf=5, status=0, action=1
04-13 17:52:11.367 11401-11421/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: callback done for clientIf - 5 status - 0
04-13 17:52:11.367 11401-11424/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureFilterParamter 500 10000 1 0
04-13 17:52:11.369 11401-11421/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onScanFilterParamsConfigured() - clientIf=5, status=0, action=0, availableSpace=15
04-13 17:52:11.369 11401-11421/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: callback done for clientIf - 5 status - 0
04-13 17:52:11.370 11401-11424/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams() - queue=1
04-13 17:52:11.370 11401-11424/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams() - ScanSetting Scan mode=2 mLastConfiguredScanSetting=-2147483648
04-13 17:52:11.370 11401-11424/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager: configureRegularScanParams - scanInterval = 8000configureRegularScanParams - scanWindow = 8000
04-13 17:52:11.371 11401-11421/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onScanParamSetupCompleted : 0
04-13 17:52:11.511 2102-5969/? I/BroadcastQueue: am_broadcast_enqueue: [background,0,Intent { act=android.bluetooth.device.action.NAME_CHANGED flg=0x4000010 (has extras) },1]
04-13 17:52:11.512 2102-2135/? I/BroadcastQueue: am_broadcast_finished: [background,0,Intent { act=android.bluetooth.device.action.NAME_CHANGED flg=0x4000010 (has extras) }]
04-13 17:52:11.519 2102-22925/? I/BroadcastQueue: am_broadcast_enqueue: [background,0,Intent { act=android.bluetooth.device.action.CLASS_CHANGED flg=0x4000010 (has extras) },2]
04-13 17:52:11.520 2102-2135/? I/BroadcastQueue: am_broadcast_finished: [background,0,Intent { act=android.bluetooth.device.action.CLASS_CHANGED flg=0x4000010 (has extras) }]
04-13 17:52:13.107 9723-9723/? W/qcom-system-dae: type=1400 audit(0.0:266139): avc: denied { read write } for name="diag" dev="tmpfs" ino=1993 scontext=u:r:qcomsysd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:diag_device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=0 ppid=1 pcomm="init" pgid=1 pgcomm="init"
04-13 17:52:13.113 9723-9723/? I/libmdmdetect: ESOC framework not supported
04-13 17:52:13.114 9723-9723/? I/libmdmdetect: Found internal modem: modem
04-13 17:52:13.114 9723-9723/? E/QCOMSysDaemon: Can't find/open bootselect node: (No such file or directory)
04-13 17:52:13.114 9723-9723/? I/QCOMSysDaemon: Starting qcom system daemon
04-13 17:52:13.114 9723-9723/? E/Diag_Lib:  Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 13
04-13 17:52:13.114 9723-9723/? E/QCOMSysDaemon:  Diag_LSM_Init failed : 0
04-13 17:52:13.356 11401-11401/? D/HeadsetPhoneState: Enter onSignalStrengthsChanged
04-13 17:52:13.356 11401-11401/? D/HeadsetPhoneState: sendDeviceStateChanged. mService=1 mSignal=2 mRoam=0 mBatteryCharge=2
04-13 17:52:13.357 11401-11401/? D/HeadsetPhoneState: Exit onSignalStrengthsChanged
04-13 17:52:13.357 11401-11434/? D/HeadsetStateMachine: Disconnected process message: 11, size: 0
04-13 17:52:16.909 11401-11401/? D/HeadsetPhoneState: Enter onSignalStrengthsChanged
04-13 17:52:16.909 11401-11401/? D/HeadsetPhoneState: sendDeviceStateChanged. mService=1 mSignal=3 mRoam=0 mBatteryCharge=2
04-13 17:52:16.909 11401-11401/? D/HeadsetPhoneState: Exit onSignalStrengthsChanged
04-13 17:52:16.910 11401-11434/? D/HeadsetStateMachine: Disconnected process message: 11, size: 0
04-13 17:52:17.541 11020-11070/? V/ClClient: SEND(415)  KeepAliveRequest_4{}    UID:784cef6d-1b6e-4f96-92ed-54b37f0eb936
04-13 17:52:17.828 11020-11068/? V/ClClient: RECV(415)  +0,3s   KeepAliveResponse_5{hasEstablishedSession=true}
04-13 17:52:18.187 9795-9795/? W/qcom-system-dae: type=1400 audit(0.0:266140): avc: denied { read write } for name="diag" dev="tmpfs" ino=1993 scontext=u:r:qcomsysd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:diag_device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=0 ppid=1 pcomm="init" pgid=1 pgcomm="init"
04-13 17:52:18.194 9795-9795/? I/libmdmdetect: ESOC framework not supported
04-13 17:52:18.195 9795-9795/? I/libmdmdetect: Found internal modem: modem
04-13 17:52:18.195 9795-9795/? E/QCOMSysDaemon: Can't find/open bootselect node: (No such file or directory)
04-13 17:52:18.195 9795-9795/? I/QCOMSysDaemon: Starting qcom system daemon
04-13 17:52:18.195 9795-9795/? E/Diag_Lib:  Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 13

Comment: Background detection is known to work fine on API 24 with most Android devices.  This may be a device-specific issue.  It is normal for background detections to be slower, but typically this is only by a few seconds.  If you wait 5-6 minutes while the app is in the background, does it eventually detect?  I ask this because the library does a fallback high powered scan every 5 minutes in the background just in case the low powered filtered scans are not working.

Comment: Another question:  please check the version of the Android Beacon Library you are using.  Only versions starting with 2.9.1 work properly with Android N.

Comment: I waited for more than 5-6 minutes and nothing changed. I set bg interval to 30 sec and scan period to 10 sec. I can see the logs about bluetooth scanning, but enterRegion event didn't be fired. I've tested the case plenty of times. Eventually, I can only reach that when i killed the app, if phone remains in region, i can get the exit event. But it works only once, after that when phone enters the region again, it does not work. Same code works well Samsung galaxy a5 with android version 6. What am i missing? Also, i checked the altbeacon library version. It is 2.9.2.

Comment: Can you please show your setup code that show starting monitoring?

Comment: Hi david, i added my Application class above. Thanked for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the Sony Z5 is not detecting Bluetooth LE packets at all when the app is in the background. **This may be a device-specific problem, or it may be a vendor-specific OS modification.**

It may help to find a workaround to capture additional debug logging (including system level debug messages, not just your app) for the period in the background where the app does a full scan.  Using your settings shown in the question, this will happen for 10 seconds every 40 seconds, and will be indicated by a debug line like this:

```
04-12 15:52:20.989 15256-15256/com.workzonemobile D/CycledLeScannerForLollipop: starting non-filtered scan in SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY
```

If you can provide such a log for a 60 second excerpt around a line like this, I may be able to ammend this answer with something more useful to solve your problem.

Comment: Hi David, i added the logs you requested at the end of my question. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: David, I switched on Sony Z5's GPS. i It works right, now. If device's bluetooth and gps are on at the same time, It detects beacon signal perfectly. Another question, is GPS needed to be on in order to detect beacon signals?

Comment: Hey, major clue!  When you say GPS on, do you mean the Location setting in Android?  If so, turning that off actually blocks BLE packet detection in Android 6+.  Could something that simple be what is going on?